# solaris + vxprint + mirror for rootvol & rootdisk7vol not exist

Tags: solaris, mirror

I run the vxprint -g rootdg
on my Solaris machine (HW- NETRA T2000)

As we see here - rootvol & rootdisk7vol has missing lines (swapvol is OK)

How to fix the rootvol & rootdisk7vol in order to bring the missing lines as we see then in swapvol ?

```
  vxprint -g rootdg
  TY NAME         ASSOC        KSTATE   LENGTH   PLOFFS   STATE    TUTIL0  PUTIL0
  dg rootdg       rootdg       -        -        -        -        -       -

  dm rootdisk     c0t1d0s2     -        286617216 -       -        -       -
  dm rootmirror   c0t3d0s2     -        286617216 -       -        -       -

  v  rootdisk7vol gen          ENABLED  122112   -        ACTIVE   -       -
  pl rootdisk7vol-01 rootdisk7vol ENABLED 122112 -        ACTIVE   -       -
  sd rootdisk-03  rootdisk7vol-01 ENABLED 122112 0        -        -       -


  v  rootvol      root         ENABLED  253016064 -       ACTIVE   -       -
  pl rootvol-01   rootvol      ENABLED  253016064 -       ACTIVE   -       -
  sd rootdisk-02  rootvol-01   ENABLED  253016064 0       -        -       -


  v  swapvol      swap         ENABLED  33479040 -        ACTIVE   -       -
  pl swapvol-01   swapvol      ENABLED  33479040 -        ACTIVE   -       -
  sd rootdisk-01  swapvol-01   ENABLED  33479040 0        -        -       -
  pl swapvol-02   swapvol      ENABLED  33479040 -        ACTIVE   -       -
  sd rootmirror-01 swapvol-02  ENABLED  33479040 0        -
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll look for my old documentation on mirroring root disk with Veritas Volume Manager since it is not quite as simple as the rest.

The simple way to mirror the volumes in `rootdg` is the same as with any other diskgroup.

```
vxassist -g rootdg mirror rootdisk7vol rootmirror
vxassist -g rootdg mirror rootvol rootmirror
```

This will create the lines you're missing the only problem is that there are problems booting with disks that have been mirrored like this if you ever decide to boot from physical slices.

I'll try to find my old documentation on the subject.